# Android 2.3.4 RTP Server and Client

Tags: android, rtp

I'm trying to implement RTP Server to transport Voice from Micro to another Phone. And RTP Client to play Audio from another Phone to my phone.

So do you have a library, demo or any mention please talk to me.

Additional, I also need a RTP Server application to test.

**UPDATE**

In case, I can get an URL like this: RTP://192.168.43.123:5678. So How to streaming it in Android 2.3.4 ?

Thank alot

Note: I must using Android 2.3.4 :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at this library: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

It uses a RTP Server and several Codecs, but unfortunately it is only for android 4.0 and above.

There is another library which works with API Level 8, but doesn't provide RTP: https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye

Comment: Thank bro, but I must implement in Android 2.3.4. But I also need an RTP Server application to test. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You can use Spydroid IP-Camera as axl coder suggested (it is for api level 9 and above) or you can build FFMPeg for Android, like this: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/

Comment: In my project, I dont know what song can be play in Server phone. Server phone only return link like that: RTP://192.168.43.123:5678. So can be FFMPEG is ok? If possible, can you give me a ffmpeg client demo? Thank for your help, sorry for my noope